# change text in object to new key typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, object, key

i have an array with object inside:

```
export const noteArr = [
  {row1: "test1", row2: "Theme: rowTheme \n" + "/row/details?id=rowId"},
];
```

then i have object noteParams which i get from my post request

```js
 for(const key of Object.keys(noteParams)){

      console.log(noteParams)// Object { rowTheme: "asd", rowId: "3768" }
      console.log(key)//rowTheme
                      //rowId
                      
       console.log(noteParams[key]) //asd
                                   // 3768
     
    }
```

how i can change in noteArr inside object `"rowTheme"` and `"rowId"` to values from noteParams

i need something like this

```
{row1: "test1", row2: "Theme: asd \n" + "/row/details?id=3768"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ???

```js
  const noteArr = [
    { row1: 'test1', row2: 'Theme: rowTheme \n' + '/row/details?id=rowId' },
  ];

  const noteParams = { rowTheme: 'asd', rowId: '3768' };

  const newValue = noteArr.map((x) => {
    return {
      ...x,
      row2: `Theme: ${noteParams.rowTheme} \n /row/details?id=${noteParams.rowId}`,
    };
  });

  console.log(newValue);
```